# c++ throwing error

Tags: c++, error-handling, throw

I am writing a c++ code that add o node to end of a list I want to throw error when a node is already exist, it is working but whenever I call it with already exiting node I get this error. Anyone know the reason and how it is fixed?

> exception terminate called after
>   throwing an instance of 'Error' 
>   Aborted

```
List& List::addnode(node p){
    node *Current=NULL;

    p.nextNode = NULL;
    p.previousNode = NULL;

    if (!firstNode) firstNode = &p;

    else Current = firstNode;
    while (Current){
            if ((*Current) == p){
                    throw NodeExist;
                    return *this;
            }
            if (!(Current->nextNode)){
                    Current->nextNode = &p;
                    p.previousNode = Current;
                    return *this;
            }
            Current = Current->nextNode;

    }

}
```

edit: I call it like that

```
try{
x.addNode(p);
x.addNode(p1);
x.addNode(p2);
x.addNode(p1);
x.addNode(p4);
}
catch(int i){
cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

if I erase one of the `x.addNode(p1);` line it work normally without an exception...

Comment: Is node being passed by value here as well, so you are getting a copy?

Comment: Can you show the definitions of `Error` and `NodeExist`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't catch and handle `NodeExist` anywhere. so it goes up the call chain all the way to main.

`catch(int i)` doesn't match `NodeExist` to catch that you need `catch(Error e)`

Comment: I add how i call it, is there any missing?

Answer (score 0):

What else were you expecting?

You `throw` an exception, and your application is terminating with the exception. It's doing what you told it to do.

To be more specific, you're not `catch`ing the exception anywhere higher up the call chain in your program, so the exception is terminating the program.